# Does facebook support access to comments made on a page event with the open graph?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to get the comments made in an event (posted to a fb page) with the open graph?

There is a page which I am creating events on and I would like to be able to get the comments made by external users on the event.

The strange thing about this is that it seems that you can get the comments of an external user made on a page so I'm not sure why the event comments aren't accessible.

(get error about link here, use open graph api url as base)
To get the comments on a page: {page_id}/feed
This will include other things besides comments, but at least the comments are there.

To get the comments on an event: {event_id}/feed
This will only include the comments made by the page(event?) owner instead of any comment made on the event.

I've looked around and it seems like this functionality may not even be supported, but I haven't found a definitive answer. I see some bug/questions that relate to what I'm doing, but none seem to be the same thing when i read them (or i'm not sure they are the same thing as the descriptions aren't very clear to me).

Example (can't link to the other):
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/379682915465545 (this sounds very close, but not really sure)

mostly just looking for a yes/no answer, though if the answer is yes and you know how to get the comments of an external user that info would be useful.

Comment: Nobody answered so I posted the question to fb: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/699317786751948

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this functionality is by design.

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/699317786751948